# Integration Testing: Am I doing it right?

Tags: c#, nunit, automated-tests, integration-testing

Here's an integration test I wrote for a class that interacts with a database:

```
[Test]
public void SaveUser()
{
    // Arrange
    var user = new User();
    // Set a bunch of properties of the above User object

    // Act
    var usersCountPreSave = repository.SearchSubscribersByUsername(user.Username).Count();
    repository.Save(user);
    var usersCountPostSave = repository.SearchSubscribersByUsername(user.Username).Count();

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(userCountPreSave + 1, userCountPostSave);
}
```

It seems to me that I can't test the `Save` function without involving the `SearchSubscriberByUsername` function to find out if the user was successfully saved. I realize that integration tests aren't meant to be unit tests which are supposed to test one unit of code at a time. But ideally, it would be nice if I could test one function in my repository class per test but I don't know how I can accomplish that.

Is it fine how I've written the code so far or is there a better way?

Comment: Which class are you testing, when do you enter initial data into database?

Comment: (Unit|Integration)Tests are useful if with them you fill more confident on the software you write and more confident on changing it. If you are don't mind too much on what is on the literature, don't break an useful test just to make it more compliant with the gurus

Comment: @Danny: I'm testing my repository class and I drop all tables and recreate them at the beginning of each test run (not before each test).

Comment: You should do that before each test is run (in TestInitialize, not ClassInitialize), otherwise your tests are dependant on each other and the order they are run. (Unless **none** of the tests write to the database.)

Comment: @Danny: isn't dropping all tables and recreating them for each test a little much? As long as the test code makes no assumptions on the state of the database, why should I recreate all tables for each test?

Comment: In the example you gave that is the state, however, shouldn't you have tests that do create a certain state and test it? E.g. Testing queries, mapping of relations between entities. At the beginning of each test you can save test's inputs to empty database, then check one method. Also, if you use a file based DB (e.g. MSSQLCE) for testing and not your main DB, you can copy an empty DB into your output directory before each test instead of dropping everything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a problem with your test. When you're testing that data is saved into the database, you should be testing that it's in the database, not that the repository says that it's in the database.

If you're testing the functionality of repository, then you can't verify that functionality by asking if it has done it correctly. It's the equivalent of saying to someone 'Did you do this correctly?' They are going to say yes.

Imagine that repository never commits. Your test will pass fine, but the data won't be in the database.

So, what I would do is to to open a connection (pure SQL) to the database and check that the data has been saved correctly. You only need to a select count(*) before and after to ensure that the user has been saved. If you do this, you can avoid using the SearchSubscribersByUsername as well.

If you're testing the functionality of repository, you can't trust repository, by definition.

Comment: I was hoping I could avoid having to do that which is why I made this post hoping to find some 'best-practice' to avoid writing the inevitable code. +1 for "If you're testing the functionality of repository, you can't trust repository, by definition."

Answer (score 2):

To unit test something like a "Save" function, you will definitely need some trustworthy channel to check the result of the operation. If you trust `SearchSubscribersByUsername` (because you have already made some unit tests for that function on its own), you can use it here.

If you don't trust `SearchSubscribersByUsername` and you think your unit test could also break because there is an error in that function (and not in `Save`), you should think about a different channel (perhaps you have a possibility to make a bypassing SQL access to your DB to check the `Save` result, which may be simpler than the implementation of `SearchSubscribersByUsername`)? However, do not reimplement `SearchSubscribersByUsername` again, that would be getting pointless.  Either way, you will need at least *some* other function you can trust.

Comment: Wouldn't any channel need to be tested first? Let's say I wrote a test for the SearchSubscriberByUsername function. Would you deem it trustworthy then?

Comment: You can trust it if you think you have enough unit tests for it. I say "you", because I don't know anything about `SearchSubcribersByUsername` and it's internal complexity, so you have to decide by yourself what "enough" means. But if you think it is (or may become) too complex to be trustworthy, and you have a much simpler and less error-prone channel to test what really is in your database, then you should use the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the method you are testing returns definitive information about what you have done I don't see any way to avoid calling other methods. I think you are correct in your assumption that Integration testing needs a different way of thinking from Unit testing.

I would still build tests that focus on individual methods. So in testing Save() I may well use the capabilities of Search(), but my focus is on the edge cases of Save(). I build tests that deal with duplicate insertions or invalid input data. Then later I build a whole raft of Search() tests that deal with the edge cases of Search().

Now one possible way of thinking is that Save and Search have some commonality, a bug in Search might mask a bug in Save. Imagine, for example, if you had a caching layer down there. So possibly an alternative approach is to use some other verification mechanism. For example a direct JDBC call to the database, or alteratively introducing mocking layers at some point in your infrastructure. When building complex Integrated Systems this kind of "Back Door" verification may be essential.

Comment: I considering writing a direct call to the database that counted the number of users in the system before and after the save operation but was wondering if that was the best practice and hence this post. There's so much material out there about unit testing making it difficult to find material on integration testing.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I've written countless tests very similar to this and think its fine. The alternative is to stub out the database so that searchSubscribers never actually does anything but thats great deal of work for what I'd say is little gain.